# pentaho log file configuration

Tags: tomcat, pentaho

I wants the pentaho log file should be created for everyday at scheduled time, even if there is no events fired on the pentaho server. Pls help where i can configure that ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would have to modify your `/path/to/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml`

Then just modify the param during which time you want the logfile to be created.

```
  <param name="File" value="pentaho.log"/>
  <param name="Append" value="false"/>

  <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

  <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Cyril's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015806/cyril-pangilinan)  purely Pentaho solution, you can also define a crontab (your server is linux, isn't it?) which copy the pentaho.log at schedule time.

Note that, in a few month, you will also want a crontab that deletes old logs, from pentaho and catalina. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22462788/1938185).